# How to solve Schrödinger's equation for this potential algebraically?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, schroedinger-equation

I want to solve Schrödinger's equation with the potential $$V(x)=\frac{1}{2}mx^2+\lambda x$$ algebraically? Is there any way to construct ladder operators that are similar to the one for the harmonic oscillator in order to get the full Hamiltonian written as $H=k_1(b^*b+k_2)$?

A good reference may be suitable as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just the potential of a standard harmonic oscillator. The presence of the linear term is just due to the fact that you're using a coordinate system where the minimum of the potential is not at $x=0$.
You can re-write it as
$$V(x)=\frac{1}{2}mx'^2+c$$
where $x'=x+\frac{\lambda}{m}$ is the coordinate centered at the minimum of the potential and $c=-\frac{\lambda^2}{2m}$ is an overall constant.